# How to extract a value if there is no column name?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

[image: Table Image]
I have an excel sheet as shown above with data of employees' attendance per month.
There is a row with heading status which shows number of absents of an employee.
Normally I would go with:

```
status = data.iloc[i].value_counts()
```

which returns the count of all the variables in that row including the heading status.

For example, the output is:

[image: Sample Output]

I only need the count of A(absents). How do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also access a specific value in "status" variable by:

```
status.loc["A"]
```

returns only the number of absents.